# Mongodb remove shard - Can't have more than one draining shard at a time

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb cluster consisting of 8 shards containing a number of databases. We have  sharded the collections which are big and left the others unsharded. Sometime back in the past when we were running 2.0, we removed two shards, so these two shards went into draining. As there were unsharded collections on these shards the draining could never finish.

Now when we have upgraded the cluster to 2.2, I tried to get rid of these two shards ( the draining ones). So I moved all the primaries to other shards and tried to remove the shard, I got this :

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { removeShard: "shard0000" } )
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Can't have more than one draining shard at a time" }
```

Now I can not remove any of the shards. I am hoping that someone will know what is going on and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you share your sh.status() output?

Comment: I have too many dbs. The output is really too big. What exactly do you want to know ?

Comment: What does it list for the shards that you have tried to remove?

Comment: As such there is no entry for any db in the database section of the output. But in the shards section following entry is there :

{  "_id" : "shard0000",  "draining" : true,  "host" : "shard0000/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017" }

Comment: @AbhayPS what did you finally do for this ?

Comment: @Srikar - What I did is : 
Connect to mongos and use config. Then remove the entry for the shard from db.shards. And then restart mongos.
Then you can safely remove the data for the shard in question.
IMPORTANT: don't forget to move the unsharded collections to other shard by moving the prmary for the db.

Comment: @AbhayPS did this cause any DB inconsistencies as the state of that shard is "draining", possibly some data has not migrated yet? or was all the data migrated to other machines but the "draining" state was not updated, which you manually took care by modifying the `db.shards`?

Comment: @Srikar - no it did not. Because the data was already drained but as we had some unsharded collection on the shards thats why it was always showing "draining". Once I moved all the primaries to the other shard then all the data migration completed. Its was still showing "draining" but in reality there was nothing left to drain.

Comment: @AbhayPS thats exactly what I thought, its got something to do with the state of the shard.Even after all the data has been migrated and the primary DB's shifted.the state has not been changed to "done".this is what you accomplished by manually removing the entry from `config.shard` collection.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be good to answer this question myself as later on I could find how to get rid of this situation. What I did was :
Firstly, moved the primaries from the shard to another shard.
When all primaries are moved to another shard then I removed the entry from the config.shard collection manually.
And finally restarted mongos. If you have more than one mongos then restart all mongos'.

Answer (score 1):

to complete the remove operation, check the status and if the chunk movement has completed, run the remove command one more time.
This will "finalize" the remove command and allow running another remove shard command.